# Rarefaction waves in traffic theory with triangular fundamental diagram?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm studying traffic theory with the conservation law of the LWR model: $\frac{d\rho}{dt}+\frac{d\Phi(\rho)}{dx}=0$ . I would like to know which is the solution obtained with the method of characteristics if I consider a triangular fundamental diagram and an initial density distribution which has congestion for x<0 and free flow for x>0, i.e.

$\rho(x,0)=\rho_L, x<0$

$\rho(x,0)=\rho_R, x>0$

with $\rho_L>\rho_R$. This problem is also known as "green light problem", because we have this distribution when vehicles are in a traffic light queue and light goes green. I have found some solution to this problem, which involves rarefaction waves, however none of them deals with triangular fundamental diagrams. 
Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Actually I found a solution here http://www.cmi.univ-mrs.fr/~herbin/PUBLI/lwr-rev.pdf so the question is closed

Comment: Why don't you just delete the question then?